# The top menu does not push from the left to right because of position fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one issue with the sidebar menu push. I have 2 menus `top menu` and `left menu`. Now when I click on the hamburger menu which is on the top menu left side then the sidebar will display.

But notice here when sidebar will display then it will push the content from left to right. Now my main issue is, the top menu does not push from the left to right because of `position fixed`.

Would you help me out?

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("left-menu").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("Wrapper").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("left-menu").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("Wrapper").style.marginLeft = "0";
}
```

```css
.left-menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

header {
  background-color: #f45800;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 65px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 65px;
}

header img,
.left-menu img {
  width: 50px;
}

.entryContent {
  padding: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-menu" id="left-menu">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeNav()"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Close_Icon_Dark-512.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="Wrapper" id="Wrapper">
  <header>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openNav()"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mini-icon-set-general-office/91/General_-_Office_30-512.png"></a>
  </header>

  <div class="entryContent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>


</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please note that the fixed menu is most likely a bad idea from usability perspective. Flicking to the top of the page is easy, but having a big part of the screen occupied is a common nuisance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will help you `document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].style.left = "250px";`

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("left-menu").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("Wrapper").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].style.left = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("left-menu").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("Wrapper").style.marginLeft = "0";
  document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].style.left = "0";
}
```

```css
.left-menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

header {
  background-color: #f45800;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 65px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 65px;
}

header img,
.left-menu img {
  width: 50px;
}

.entryContent {
  padding: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-menu" id="left-menu">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeNav()"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-actions-icons-9/792/Close_Icon_Dark-512.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="Wrapper" id="Wrapper">
  <header>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="openNav()"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mini-icon-set-general-office/91/General_-_Office_30-512.png"></a>
  </header>

  <div class="entryContent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>


</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. it's working. Can help me why you used ("header")[0]?

Comment: header[0] used only tag names, like header,footer like html tags

Comment: [document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) will return array of the elements which are `header` and I'm piking up the 1st element by using [0]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the id too header..

**HTML:**

```
<header id="header"></header>
```

**Script**

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.left = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("header").style.left = "0";
}
```